# Start/end of regex in TokensRegex

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

Suppose I have the following code:

```
TokenSequencePattern p = TokenSequencePattern.compile("[{tag:/JJ.*/}] [{tag:/NN.*/}]");
TokenSequenceMatcher m = tPattern.getMatcher(coreLabelList);
while (tMatcher.find()){
    List<CoreMap> matches = m.groupNodes();
}
```

What I would like to capture here is an adjective followed by a noun, i.e. it must start with one adjective and it must end with one noun. For example, if I have "beautiful scarf" it should be a match, but if I have "beautiful scarf with white dots" it shouldn't be a match. For now, the token regex from above is a match for both of the phrases. How do I specify the exact start of a sequence and it's exact end?

Comment: This gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
TokenSequencePattern p = TokenSequencePattern.compile("[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]");
```

Testing with `A round ball is bouncing very high in to the blue sky.` yielded `round ball` and `blue sky` substrings.

To only get *an entire string match*, you need to use *anchors* if you want to use `Matcher#find()` (with `Matcher#matches()`, the anchors are implied).

So, to only match `round ball` string as a combination of an adjective and a noun, you may use

```
TokenSequencePattern p = TokenSequencePattern.compile("^[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]$");
```

or

```
TokenSequencePattern p = TokenSequencePattern.compile("\\A[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]\\z");
```

The `^` / `\A` stand for the beginning of a string (also, `\A` will always match at the beginning of a string) and  `$` / `\z` match the end of  a string (note that `\z` will always match the very end of the string while `$` - even if you are not using a multiline modifier - allows a trailing newline after it).

**Note:** the anchors are tested on CoreNLP 3.7.0. They don't work on some versions (e.g. don't work on CoreNLP 3.5.1, it throws an error: `Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "^" (94), after : ""`)

Comment: This is not what I need. I need exactly a pattern that starts with an adjective and ends with a noun. In your case, the input starts with a determiner and ends with a noun, so it shouldn't give a match.

Comment: `JJ` stands for an adjective, not a determiner. A determiner is specified as `DT`. See http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html. The `"[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]"` yields all occurrences of `ADJ`+`space`+`NOUN` (just as you wrote *What I would like to capture here is an adjective followed by a noun*).

Comment: I know what JJ stands for, your example `A round ball...` starts with a determiner ("A" is a determiner, not an adjective). I want to match only the phrases starting with an adjective and ending with a noun, your case - starts with a determiner, I don't want to capture "round ball" or "blue sky", but rather the whole testing phrase if matches the starting and ending POS tags.

Comment: That is not  a problem of this regex, but how you use it. I used with `.find()`. If you need *a whole string match*, use it with `matches()`. Else, you need to use anchors, `^` and `$` around the pattern, i.e. `"^[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]$"`

Comment: Exactly! The anchors is what I need. However, when I put anchors in the expression `"^[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]$"` it throws an error - `Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "^" (94), after : ""` Any way to deal with this with TokenRegex?

Comment: I have just tried `"^[tag:/JJ.*/] [tag:/NN.*/]$"` with `matcher.find()` and used "round ball" as input, and got a match, no exceptions. Note I am using the latest 3.7.0 Stanford NLP package.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I use 3.5.1, probably that's why. Thanks for your help, please update your answer so I can accept it. Cheers